# Growth of the zeroes of a family of functions.

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, roots

(I'm going to be informal...and I'm not sure of what I've done so far)

Let 
$$
f_n(x) = 3^{x+1}+2(x-n)-1
$$

I define for $n \geq 1$ the value $x_n$ as the zero of $f_n$ (easy to prove it exists and it is also unique). I want to prove that $x_n$ grows as a log function, as $n$ diverges.

My attempt to show it is the following, for all $n$ I define

$$
g_n(x)=\min \left\{3^{x+1} - 2n, f_n(x) \right\} =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
f_n(x) & x < \frac{1}{2} \\
3^{x+1} - 2n & x > \frac{1}{2}
\end{array}
\right. .
$$

We have that $g_n$ is continuous and monotonically increasing, the limits at $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ have opposite signs therefore there must be a unique zero. We also observe that if $n > \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$ we have

$$
g_n(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow 3^{x+1}-2n=0 \Leftrightarrow x = t_n = \log_3(2n)-1
$$

Also it must result $x_n < t_n$ for $n$ large enough therefore I can say $x_n = O(\ln n)$. Is this derivation correct? I wish I was able to find more accurate results if this were correct.

(By the way... by "zero" I meant "root").

Answer (score 1):

For each fixed $x \geq 0$, $f_n(x) \to -\infty$ as $n \to \infty$. Also,

$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f_n(x) = \infty
$$

and $f_n(x)$ is a strictly increasing function of $x$. It follows that $f_n$ has a unique zero $x_n$ with

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \infty.
$$

This zero satisfies

$$
3^{x_n+1} + 2x_n - 1 = 2n
$$

or, dividing by $2$ and taking logarithms,

$$
\log\!\left(\tfrac{e}{2} 3^{x_n} + x_n - \tfrac{1}{2}\right) = \log n. \tag{1}
$$

As $n \to \infty$ we have

$$
\tfrac{1}{2} 3^{x_n+1} + x_n - \tfrac{1}{2} \sim \tfrac{3}{2} 3^{x_n},
$$

and so

$$
\log\!\left(\tfrac{e}{2} 3^{x_n} + x_n - \tfrac{1}{2}\right) = \log\!\left(\tfrac{3}{2}3^{x_n}\right) + o(1) = x_n \log 3 + \log(3/2) + o(1).
$$

Substituting this into $(1)$ yields

$$
x_n \log 3 + \log(3/2) + o(1) = \log n
$$

or, after rearranging,

$$
x_n = \log_3 n + \log_3(2) - 1 + o(1)
$$

as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Two questions. 1) Is my derivation wrong? 2) Why do you have $\frac{1}{2}3^{x_n+1} + x_n - \frac{1}{2} \sim \frac{3}{2}3^{x_n}$?

Comment: Didn't you also achieve my same result? (except for the order)

Comment: @user8469759 1) Your derivation seems correct. 2) For $y \in \mathbb R$ we have $\tfrac{1}{2} 3^{y+1} + y - \tfrac{1}{2} \sim \tfrac{3}{2} 3^y$ as $y \to \infty$ since $$\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{\tfrac{1}{2} 3^{y+1} + y - \tfrac{1}{2}}{\tfrac{3}{2} 3^y} = 1.$$ Then, since $x_n \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$, we have $\tfrac{1}{2}3^{x_n+1} + x_n - \tfrac{1}{2} \sim \tfrac{3}{2}3^{x_n}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @user8469759 "Didn't you also achieve my same result?" I'm not sure what you mean. You showed that $x_n = O(\log n)$, but this is only an upper bound.

Comment: My $t_n$ is exactly your final $x_n$ minus the error term, that's what I meant. Also how can can you be sure that $x_n$ diverges?

Comment: @user8469759 since $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = -\infty$$ for all fixed $x$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f_n(x) = \infty$, we conclude that for each $x$ there is an $N > 0$ such that $x < x_n$ for all $n > N$.

Comment: I'm not sure of why you can conclude that, I have to meditate on that.

Comment: @user8469759, Put differently, since $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = -\infty$, for each fixed $x$ there is an $N > 0$ such that $f_n(x) < 0$ for all $n > N$. Since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f_n(x) = \infty$, by the intermediate value theorem $f_n(x)$ has a zero in $(x,\infty)$. In other words, $x_n > x$.